# R memory management while webscraping

Tags: r, memory, memory-management, web-scraping

I have built this function which I run in a loop over a list of ~1million URLs in order to do some webscraping, but after a while my memory is full and R shuts down.

```
library(tm.plugin.webmining)

getContents <- function(url) {
out <- tryCatch(
{extractContentDOM(url, asText = F,threshold=0.5)},
error=function(cond) {
message(paste("URL does not seem to exist:", 
message("Here's the original error message:")
message(cond)
return(NA)},
warning=function(cond) {
message(paste("URL caused a warning:", url))
message("Here's the original warning message:")
message(cond)
return(NA)},
finally={
message(paste("Processed URL:", url))})    
return(out)}

#save text
a=getContents(http://www.nytimes.com/)
```

If I do so, I always get a problem regarding memory management. Basically I loop through the list of URLs, extract the text, analyze it.

Every time I run the function, it increases the used memory by some MB. When you then try to release the memory to system with

```
rm(list = ls())
gc()
```

the task manager does not does not show that memory has been given back to the system; after a while there's a system shutdown because there's no available memory left. I also tried to restart R, but there seems to be no way to restart R in a loop, so that the loop goes on afterwards.
Ive already read a lot about that topic, but I didnt find a proper answer to that problem yet.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have such a large web scraping, I would encourage you to store on hard drive as it goes through for each site instead of memory.  At least that is what I've done in the past and has worked really well.

Comment: even if I go for that, the memory problem is still not solved; it won't loop through all the URLs